# Motorized midi fader BCF2000 driver

Tags: ros, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know where I can get a copy of the bcf2000_driver?

This was originally mentioned in the question here "answers.ros.org/question/33234/looking-for-a-usb-mixer-ros-interface/?answer=33304#post-id-33304", that points to the now deprecated "kforge.ros.org/sandbox/bcf2000_driver".

Thanks,
ioannis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139606/motorized-midi-fader-bcf2000-driver/) by [i.havoutis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13256/i.havoutis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As kforge is no more, I quickly cooked up a new bcf2000 driver as I could not find the old one anywhere...

You can get a copy of the driver here: github.com/ihavoutis/bcf2000.git

cheers

---

Originally posted by [i.havoutis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13256/i.havoutis/) with karma: 36 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1